# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to bind

Tags: process, apache-storm, netstat

**When i submitted topology i got in worker log file**

```
[ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker 
org.apache.storm.netty.channel.ChannelException: **Failed to bind to: 
0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6703** at 
org.apache.storm.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) 
~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5] at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Server.<init>
(Server.java:130) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5] at 
backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context.bind(Context.java:75) ~[storm-
core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5] at 
backtype.storm.messaging.loader$launch_receive_thread_BANG_.doInvoke(loader.clj:
68) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5] at 
clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:668) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na] at 
backtype.storm.daemon.worker$launch_receive_thread.invoke(worker.clj:378) 
~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5] at
```

the version i'm using

```
storm version 0.9.5
zookeeper -3.4.6
```

Comment: Normally you get an exception like this when the port is already in use.  Try and determine if any processes are currently running already on port 6703.  You don't really give enough information to determine anything else.

Comment: i'm new to storm so what exactly information do you need to help ?

Comment: The code you are using is usually useful.  And like I said, determine first if something is using port 6703.

Comment: i used this command ps -ef|grep 6703 and got this username 4162 3449 0 02:32 pts/8 00:00:00 grep --color=auto 6703